# PdfViewer Android - missing classes

Tags: android, xml, github, pdf-viewer

Added this to the activity.xml

`<com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView android:id="@+id/pdfView" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="500dp"/>`

dependency
`implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1'`

even after syncing the build the class is not available

Tried undoing the dependency and synced without it and later added again which still did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Try to invalidate Caches in your Android Studio

Comment: Thanks tried invalidating the cache but still the same, any other solution would really help. completely fresh to Android Studio external libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing this [issue](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer/issues/1107) because the original repo is published using Jcenter, which is now deprecated on Android.

As mentioned in the issue that I linked, there is a [fork](https://github.com/mhiew/AndroidPdfViewer) of the original project (published as `mhiew/AndroidPdfViewer`) that is now also published on maven and you can use that to import the library.